# How can I add an indented line in the end of a yaml file with bash?

Tags: bash, shell, file, yaml, sh

I have a file test.yaml with content:

```
'12345'
  key1: 'foo'
  key2: 'bar'
```

I have a system/env variable called ENV1 with value "baz"

How can I have this file as an outcome with bash?

```
'12345':
  key1: 'foo'
  key2: 'bar'
  key3: 'baz'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed "\$a\  key3: '$ENV1'" file 

'12345'
  key1: 'foo'
  key2: 'bar'
  key3: 'baz'
```

or set `-i` for in place.

Another alternative

```
$ cat file <(echo "  key3: '$ENV1'")
```

Comment: I get an error ""$a\  key3: ''": extra characters after \ at the end of a command"

Comment: make sure you have the quotes exactly as written.  If you're on MacOS, sed has some quirks there, check the docs for adding a line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this the easiest approach (this will write to the file):

```
echo "  key3: '$ENV1'" >> file
```

If just want to print appending the content of the environment variable (not modifying the file)

```
cat file <(echo "  key3: '$ENV1'")
```